# Bitbucket Server Plugin: get diff of commits

Tags: git, plugins, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to write a plugin for Bitbucket Server, which will inspect the code that was modified. To be able to do this, I'd like to read the contents of each commit (files changed, contents of new file vs contents of the old file).

I've looked through all of the Bitbucket Server plugin documentation, but have been unable to find any examples of this. Moreover, I've also explored every possible object returned in the callbacks (see code attached below), and none of them contain what I'm looking for.

```
public class MyPreRepositoryHook implements PreRepositoryHook<RepositoryPushHookRequest> {

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext context,
                                          @Nonnull RepositoryPushHookRequest request) {

        final RefChange next = request.getRefChanges().iterator().next();
        final SimpleMinimalRef ref = (SimpleMinimalRef) next.getRef();

        // ref has nothing useful :(

        return RepositoryHookResult.rejected("failed", "failed details");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnd(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext context, @Nonnull RepositoryPushHookRequest request, @Nonnull RepositoryHookResult result) {

    }
}
```

How can I get the contents of each commit?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FileSize/FileName Hook plugin](https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/christiangalsterer/stash/filehooks/plugin/hook/FileNameHook.java) on github:

```
        Collection<RefChange> filteredRefChanges = refChanges.stream().filter(isNotDeleteRefChange).filter(isNotTagRefChange).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if(branchesPattern.isPresent()) {
            filteredRefChanges = filteredRefChanges.stream().filter(matchesBranchPattern(branchesPattern.get())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        Iterable<Change> changes = changesetService.getChanges(filteredRefChanges, repository);

        Collection<String> filteredPaths = StreamSupport.stream(changes.spliterator(), false).filter(isNotDeleteChange).map(Functions.CHANGE_TO_PATH).filter(setting.getIncludePattern().asPredicate()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if(setting.getExcludePattern().isPresent()) {
            Pattern excludePattern = setting.getExcludePattern().get();
            filteredPaths = filteredPaths.stream().filter(excludePattern.asPredicate().negate()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```